# How do I slow down the opening crawl in Lego Star Wars?

Tags: lego-star-wars

I like reading out the [Opening Crawl](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Opening_crawl) (the yellow scrolling text - [example here](http://www.starwars.com/games/playnow/crawl_creator/index.jsp?cs=wrbrnugum3)) between levels in Lego Star Wars, but I find it goes a bit too quickly. Can I slow it down?

[image: Text of question in Opening Crawl]

Comment: For what platform did you purchase the game?

Comment: @unforgettableid PlayStation (not sure which version).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PC, Wii, Xbox or PS2/3? If it's a Wii, forget it there are *rarely* any configuration options for games. I doubt other flavors will have any other options either.

In any case, the easiest (albeit lamest) way would be to just record it using software (such as [Fraps](http://www.fraps.com/)) or a video camera to play back to your hearts content. ;)
Alternately, you could perhaps muster searching powers (better than my own failed attempts) to find a webpage with the texts already written down?

To note, according to the [LEGO Star Wars: The Complete Saga Wikia entry](http://lego.wikia.com/wiki/LEGO_Star_Wars:_The_Complete_Saga), there are 6 chapters and 6 episodes, so there's *only* 36 rolling texts to read. Enjoy! ;)